# Unique solutions to ODE without global Lipschitz condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions, initial-value-problems

I am interested in uniqueness results for autonomous nonlinear ODEs which do not satisfy a local Lipschitz condition. To show my though process I give some preliminary results and successively state my questions in paragraphs **3), 4)** and **5)**.

Consider the following IVP
\begin{align}
\dot{x}(t) & = f(x(t)),\\
x(0) & = x^0 \in \mathbb{R}^n,
\end{align}
with $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, continuous and locally Lipschitz continuous almost everywhere. Continuity gives the existence of solutions by Peano's Theorem. When do we get unique solutions?

**1)** The setting above is obviously to broad to guarantee uniqueness. See the classical counter example for the one-dimensional case ($n=1$):
\begin{align}
\dot{x}(t) & = f(x(t)) = 2\sqrt{|x(t)|},\\
x(0) & = 0,
\end{align}
with solutions $x(t) = 0$ and $x(t) = t^2$.

**2)** I will change the ODE above to get a related system. There are nonunique solutions because the point $x = 0$ where $f(x)$ is not locally Lipschitz has the property $f(0) = 0$. A solution can stay in $x = 0$ or slowly move away from it. Therefore, I want to consider the system
\begin{align}
\dot{x}(t) & = f(x(t)) = 2\sqrt{|x(t)|} + \varepsilon,\\
x(0) & = 0,
\end{align}
with $\varepsilon \neq 0$. I think in this case the initial value problem possesses unique (global) solutions.  For $\varepsilon > 0$ we have $f(x) \ge \varepsilon > 0$ and in this case we get unique solutions.  For the case $\varepsilon < 0$ there exists a neighborhood of $x = 0$ where $f(x) < \delta < 0$. So locally there is a unique solution which we then can extend in a unique way using the Lipschitz continuity of $\sqrt{x}$ away from zero. This might not be completely rigorous so please point out any flaws.

**3)** This observation brings me to my first conjecture:

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$. Assume the following assumptions are met.

1. $f$ is locally Lipschitz continuous on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \Omega$.
2. $\Omega$ consist out of isolated points.
3. $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in \Omega$.

Then the IVP

\begin{align}
\dot{x}(t) & = f(x(t)),\\
x(0) & = x^0 \in \mathbb{R},
\end{align}

has a uniqe local solution for all $x^0 \in \mathbb{R}$. Is this true? If it is false, can someone give a counter example? If this is true, can it be shown the way I discussed the system in **2)**?

In addition, I want to know if this holds in the higher dimensions:

**4)** Does **3)** hold in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

**5)** (Bonus) I would also like to know if one can extend the assumptions in **3)** to get unique global solutions. Maybe this can be attained if one can guarantee that the elements in $\Omega$ are uniformly isolated ($\lVert \omega_1 - \omega_2\rVert > 4\delta > 0$ for $\omega_1 \neq \omega_2 \in \Omega$) while imposing a global Lipschitz condition on $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \bigcup_{\omega \in \Omega} B(\omega, \delta)$ with an additional bound of $f$ on $\bigcup_{\omega \in \Omega} B(\omega, \delta)$.

Thank you for taking the time to read everything. I would be really glad if some of you could answer my questions or hint me at some helpful sources!

Kind regards, AverageJoe